# KeyboardAwareScrollView extra height with multiple textinputs

Tags: react-native

I have a screen with 2 text inputs inside a [KeyboardAwareScrollView](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view):

[image]

When the user fills the text inputs, an action button appears in the bottom:

[image]

I want the action button to be always visible if the user fills all the details, so i did the following:

```
<View style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0, padding: 20, paddingBottom: 30 }}>
// the button goes here
</View>
```

The problem is that the button covers the last text input if the keyboard is open:

[image]

So i added `extraScrollHeight` and `extraHeight` to the `KeyboardAwareScrollView`, it works fine if there are no already focused `textInputs`.

However, if there is an already focused `textInput` and the user presses on another one, no extra scroll space is added.

Meaning that if the user presses on the name field, fill his name and then presses on email field,`extraScrollHeight` will be ignored.

My container looks like the following:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
    {...this.props}
    enableOnAndroid
    extraScrollHeight={80}
    extraHeight={80}>

    {this.props.children}

</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

DEMO:

[image]